# DevTools Styles not available

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On Google Chrome: 54.0.2840.87 (64-bit)
when inspecting an element,
devtools ( Elements tab ) does not show styles.

[image: Styles not available]

On another PC, same chrome version, styles are showed correctly.
What can cause this problem ?

Comment: There's no setting to hide styles so it's either a bug or a problem with that computer. Try reinstalling Chrome.

Comment: Seems to be a chrome problem when opening with a custom data-dir. Chrome Beta seems not to be affected